# jtextarea resize java swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am working on Java Swing now ,  but as you can see in the picture below , I cannot resize(increase width) my textarea box . 
It only resizes if I change the width of outer jframe or if I maximise the window. 
Please help.
[image: java swing example]

```
JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Java Tryout");
    jframe.setSize(500, 400);
    jframe.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    jframe.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel( "", JLabel.LEFT );
    JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel( "", JLabel.LEFT );

    statusLabel.setSize(350, 100);

    JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
    controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    jframe.add(headerLabel);
    jframe.add(controlPanel);
    jframe.add(statusLabel);
    jframe.setVisible(true);
```

This is my code. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Yes, different layouts are used for the contents to fill the frame as it is resized... take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html. I tend to use the old GridBagLayout  with alot of parameters for how content should span and fill..., maybe the most complex one but ones you get how it works... it does what ever you like...

Comment: btw, the code you posted does not really do the image you posted... ; )

Comment: yes but my window sizing problem only needs these code snippets , right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some other layout, one that respects component sizes. Than you can use setMaximumSize, setMinimumSize, setPerferredSize and setSize. I suggest you use something like BoxLayout or GridBagLayout.
A useful link: [A visual guild to layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)